# jQuery Nested Templates using options parameter

Tags: jquery-templates

I don't understand how to reference the options parameter in nested templates.

Please see:

```
<div id="myContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmplMain = "<div><span>${title}</span>" + 
                   "<p style=\"border: solid 1px #f00\">${$item.details}</p>" +
                   "{{tmpl \"nestedTemplate\"}}</div>";

    var tmplNested = "<p style=\"border: solid 1px #0f0\">${$item.details}</p>";

    var _mainTemplate = jQuery.template("mainTemplate", tmplMain);
    jQuery.template("nestedTemplate", tmplNested);

    var _data = {title: "My Title"};
    var _options = {details: "My Details};

    jQuery.tmpl(_mainTemplate, _data, _options).appendTo("#myContainer");
</script>
```

Which will output this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7A7g.jpg

So either I'm not referencing "${$item.details}" correctly in the nested template or I'm not passing the options correctly in the {{ tmpl }} tag.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to pass any options that you want to the `{{tmpl}}` tag.  Something like:

```
{{tmpl($data, { details: $item.details}) "nestedTemplate" }}
```

You could even just pass $item for the options to the nested template, but $item has more than just your options on it.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Xzgpr/

Comment: TYVM I ended up doing

{{tmpl($data,$item) "nestedTemplate"}}

Comment: If you template is recursively nested (calls itself on a sub-portion of the current `$item.data`), `{{tmpl($data,$item) "nestedTemplate"}}` will cause a stack overflow. I believe it is because the second `$item`'s `$item.data` ends up taking over for the `$data` parameter, which works fine in for non-recursive nested templates because they are the same. If anyone finds a way to pass just the functions without explicitly passing each one, I have a pending [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285305/recursive-jquery-templates-with-custom-functions-causing-stack-overflow).

Comment: After reading through the jQuery Templates source for [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285305/recursive-jquery-templates-with-custom-functions-causing-stack-overflow/7478025), using `$item` as the options parameter will likely cause problems for people. In this case, the `{{tmpl($data,$item) "nestedTemplate"}}` version is equivalent to `{{tmpl(null,$item) "nestedTemplate"}}` because `$item.data` is overridden from current template. Things can get very strange depending on how you call nested templates. Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/kHSg6/).