# Recursive jQuery Templates with custom functions causing stack overflow?

Tags: jquery-templates

I'm creating a jQuery Template system that recursively calls the same template as needed. Most of the examples of "recursive" templates are actually just templates calling other templates, even the ones that [pass around the `$item` object to retain custom functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263036/jquery-nested-templates-using-options-parameter/5263407#5263407). In this case, I want to call the same template with a sub-portion of the original `$data` (AKA `$item.data`) while also passing around custom template functions passed in to the options of the original `tmpl` call.

```
// original template call
$("#someTemplate").tmpl(data, {
    someFunction1: function(itemToCheck) {
        return itemToCheck.p3;
    },
    someFunction2: function(itemToCheck) {
        return itemToCheck.p1 + ", " + itemToCheck.p2;
    }
}).appendTo(".results");

<!--in-template secondary call-->
{{tmpl($data.sub, $item) "#someTemplate"}}
```

[Full code jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/YBFqR/)

It seems that passing around `$item` as the options parameter for the recursive call results in the data parameter being ignored, probably because `$item.data` contains the original object and it simply overwrites the new data parameter. As a result, at each recursive level, I am still operating at the original caller level in the object and making no further progress in the object structure (hence the stack issue).

Is there some other property of `$item` I need to use to pass around only the custom functions without having `$item.data` override the template data being passed in?

#### Update

You definitely cannot just pass `$item` as the options parameter to `{{tmpl}}`. After [looking at the code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.js#L30), it sets `data` for the new template call and then blows it away with the original `$item.data` through `jQuery.extend` a few lines later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot seem to find a variable on `$item` that wraps all the custom functions, I was able to work around this issue by passing in each custom function individually from the original `$item` object. Not ideal, but it works.

```
{{tmpl($data.sub, { someFunction1: $item.someFunction1, someFunction2: $item.someFunction2 }) "#someTemplate"}}
```